# Scraping data with rvest from a form

Tags: html, r, rvest

I would like to scrape data from this link: http://dati.acs.beniculturali.it/CPC/CPC.detail.html?A00001

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

url <- 'http://dati.acs.beniculturali.it/CPC/CPC.detail.html?A00001'
read_html(url) %>%
  html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="dataContainer"]/div[1]') %>%
  html_text()
```

As far as I understand, the problem seems to be that the data is not in table format - I could then use `html_table()` to extract what I need. Looking at the HTML structure, the div is nested into a series of divs that are included in a form. I also tried:

```
read_html(url) %>% 
  html_node('form') %>%
  html_text()
```

But I only get a series of \n. What am I missing?

Comment: Could it be that you need to log-in before you can access the data in the URL. Also, I think you need quotes before and after your URL

Comment: Yeah, I'm also afraid the actual data is protected (I'm not very good with rvest, but continously try). After you added the quotes try `read_html(url) %>%   
  html_node(".persona") %>% 
  html_text()`. This is how far I got (shows rows but no data).

Comment: Hi there, thanks. I actually forgot quotes only here in the question. It seems that log in isn't required.